# Assertion failure issue in icviewpage library in iOS

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I implemented icviewpager in my iOS application. i have 3 tabs everything working fine. The problem is when i switch between the tabs too fast the app is getting crashed with the following exception.

Assertion failure in -[_UIQueuingScrollView _enqueueCompletionState:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/_UIQueuingScrollView.m:499.

using All exeption break poing I found it's crashing at line.

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]

direction:(activeContentIndex < self.activeContentIndex) ? UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward

animated:YES

completion:^(BOOL completed) {

weakSelf.animatingToTab = NO;

}];
```

Please can you tell me how to fix this. If more information need from my side let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask the developer of that library.

Comment: ya i already posted to developer But it is some what related to UIPagecontroller thats why i posted here if anybody give me idea about this so i can look at on